# Intrinsic CPT phase

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, spin-statistics, cpt-symmetry

Under charge conjugation C, spatial inversion P and time reversal T transformations, there are possible intrinsic phases (more for this on Chapter 9, The Quantum Theory of Field v1 by S. Weinberg):

$$C \Big|\Psi; \vec{p},\sigma \Big\rangle = \Big| \Psi^c; \vec{p},\sigma \Big\rangle $$

$$P \Big| \Psi; \vec{p},\sigma \Big\rangle = \eta_P | \Psi; -\vec{p},\sigma \Big\rangle $$

$$T \Big| \Psi; \vec{p},\sigma \Big\rangle = \eta_T (-)^{s-\sigma} \Big| \Psi; -\vec{p}, -\sigma \Big\rangle $$

The $CPT$ theorem can be seen, if $\eta_C \eta_P \eta_T$ is set to $1$. My question is, if we have the freedom to choose the values of these $\eta$ (it's not the case, for example, for real field $\eta_C$ and $\eta_P$ should only be $\pm 1$, but still, for the sake of completeness ...), then why not set them all to $1$ in the first place? If these values are indeed restricted, then why one can gets $\eta_C \eta_P \eta_T = 1$, FOR ALL FIELDS / PARTICLES, in the first place?

Or the fact that $\eta_C \eta_P \eta_T = 1$ is related to something deeper, say, the axiomatic quantum field theory (the claim is that AQFT was used to proof CPT "rigourously", but I never learn and try to confirm it)?